# procedural PHP mysql SELECT prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

The person that taught me prepared statements done so as a security measure however, I realise that they are designed to limit the amount of HTTP requests to the server?

The code I have works but I don't think I'm using prepared statements properly. Here's my code.

This first section pulls the data from the database to be displayed on the edit blog posts page.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['p_id'])) {
    $get_post_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['p_id']); 
}

**$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = ? ";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $get_post_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);**

$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $post_author = $row['post_author'];
    $post_title = $row['post_title']; 
    $post_cat_id = $row['post_cat_id'];
    $post_status = $row['post_status']; 
    $post_image = $row['post_image']; 
    $post_content = $row['post_content'];    
    $post_tags = $row['post_tags']; 
    $post_date = $row['post_date']; 

}
```

The second section captures the edited data ready to insert using sql UPDATE.

```
if(isset($_POST['update_post'])) {
    $post_title         = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['title']);
    $post_author        = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['post_author']);
    $post_cat_id        = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['post_category']);
    $post_status        = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['post_status']);   
    $post_image         = $_FILES['post_image']['name'];
    $post_image_temp    = $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'];   
    $post_tags          = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['post_tags']);
    $post_content       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['post_content']);

    move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "images/$post_image");
```

This next bit of code inserts the image that is already in the database so that that if the image is not edited by the user it won't disappear.

```
if(empty($post_image))  {  

    **$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = ? ";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $get_post_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);**

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $post_image = $row['post_image']; 
    }
}
```

As you can see though, I'm querying the database twice with the same prepared statement which seems a bit redundant. Is there another way to pull the data from the db in the second instance without having to use the whole query again?

I thought foregoing the prepared statement and just using the while loop would work with the $result string as the parameter, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

**EDIT: I have managed to get the cut the code down by using just these two lines.**

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
```

**What I don't understand though is why do I need to execute the prepared statement again when it hasn't been closed? And why does the string $result not work without executing the code again?**

Comment: why are you using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` **and** a prepared statement at the same time? Probably why it's failing.

Comment: Is all that code in the same script?

Comment: _The second section captures the edited data ready to insert using sql UPDATE._ **What UPDATE**

Comment: If you dont destroy `$row` from the first query, that array is still available and containing the result of the first query. You dont actually need to do any database access in the second SELECT query code, just us `$row`

Comment: 1. I'm using mysqli_real_escape_string because I followed a tutorial that said to do it as an added security measure. It isn't needed but the code does work.
2.The code is all the same script.
3. The update code isn't included because it works, I'm just trying to understand how to make the code more simple.

Comment: Prepared statements already take care of making input safe because it separates the input from the command. Escaping it further will cause undesired effects.

Comment: In that case I will remove mysqli_real_escape_string. Thanks.